# Shape not following path designated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having some issues with a shape following a path, I want MyCircle to follow the path I created. When I run the code, the shape is not following the path I want, it is off center. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here is some XAML code that generates a canvas with a path and some shapes.

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
<Canvas Margin="5">
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MyPathStroke" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="MyPath" Figures="M421.9,110 C421.9,170.47518 327.5664,219.5 211.2,219.5 C94.833603,219.5 0.5,170.47518 0.5,110 C0.5,49.52482 94.833603,0.5 211.2,0.5 C327.5664,0.5 421.9,49.52482 421.9,110 Z" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Red" >
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry 
                x:Name="MyCircle"
                Center="110,421.9" 
                RadiusX="10" 
                RadiusY="10" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Ellipse x:Name="MyQueue" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="80" Width="80" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="270" Canvas.Top="10" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyActivity" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="50" Width="100" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="260" Canvas.Top="240" />
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

Here is my code to assign the circle to the path.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          

            PointAnimationUsingPath pa = new PointAnimationUsingPath();

            pa.PathGeometry = MyPath;

            pa.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

            pa.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

            MyCircle.BeginAnimation(EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty, pa);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So first, what are you working in? Is that WPF? Second, you don't need that code behind, you could just do a [DoubleAnimationUsingPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a storyboard instead. Second, you're off center because you'll want to use RenderTransformOrigin instead of just grabbing the center property of the ellipse.

Comment: Yes this is WPF. Ok that's what I wasn't sure of because when I changed the center nothing was happening.

Comment: Cool, just shout if you run into troubles, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning of the path (Canvas Top/Left) might work for you:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
<Canvas Margin="5">
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MyPathStroke" Stroke="Blue" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="MyPath" Figures="M421.9,110 C421.9,170.47518 327.5664,219.5 211.2,219.5 C94.833603,219.5 0.5,170.47518 0.5,110 C0.5,49.52482 94.833603,0.5 211.2,0.5 C327.5664,0.5 421.9,49.52482 421.9,110 Z" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Red" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="100">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry 
            x:Name="MyCircle"
            RadiusX="10" 
            RadiusY="10" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Ellipse x:Name="MyQueue" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="80" Width="80" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="270" Canvas.Top="10" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyActivity" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="50" Width="100" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="260" Canvas.Top="240" />
</Canvas>
```